# AndroidStudioで実機テストができない

Tags: android-studio

初投稿です。よろしくお願いします。

AndroidStudioで実機テストを行う時に、「(アプリ名)が停止しました」というアラートが表示され、再起動すると「「(アプリ名)」が繰り返し停止しています」とまたアラートが表示されます。アプリを実機で試すことができません。スマホの機種はandroidoneです。

PCやスマホの再起動、アプリの再インストール、キャッシュファイルの削除など、自分なりの改善策やいろいろなサイトの情報を試しましたが、改善しませんでした。

原因や解決策を教えてください。

Comment: logcatに表示されているエラーの内容はどうなっていますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「(アプリ名)が停止しました」というアラートが表示されるということは、何らかの例外が起きている可能性があります。
M.M.さんがおっしゃっているようにLogcatの内容を確認してください。
赤字でExceptionのような文字が表示されていれば、例外が起きている証拠です。

その赤文字の文章に解決のヒントが書かれているので、それをもとにエラーの原因となっているコードを見つけてください。
赤字の文章(スタックトレース)の読み方は[ここ](https://ittoybox.com/archives/588)に載っています。